Failed to connect Solana RPC node on localhost
  GNU nano 7.2                                                                                    validator.sh                                                                                              
GNU nano 7.2                                                                                    validator.sh
#!/bin/bash

agave-validator \
    --identity /home/ubuntu/sol/validator-keypair.json \
    --known-validator DtdSSG8ZJRZVv5Jx7K1MeWp7Zxcu19GD5wQRGRpQ9uMF \
    --known-validator CW9C7HBwAMgqNdXkNgFg9Ujr3edR2Ab9ymEuQnVacd1A \
    --known-validator HEL1USMZKAL2odpNBj2oCjffnFGaYwmbGmyewGv1e2TU \
    --known-validator q9XWcZ7T1wP4bW9SB4XgNNwjnFEJ982nE8aVbbNuwot \
    --known-validator GoeW4aFK4dGoekJySgUynWDxBZiQJqm8GDAF4H53tDK9 \
    --known-validator krakeNd6ednDPEXxHAmoBs1qKVM8kLg79PvWF2mhXV1 \
    --only-known-rpc \
    --full-rpc-api \
    --no-voting \
    --ledger /mnt/ledger \
    --accounts /mnt/accounts \
    --log /home/ubuntu/sol/solana-rpc.log \
    --rpc-port 8899 \
    --rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 \
    --private-rpc \
    --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001
    --expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d \
    --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
    --limit-ledger-size


Here are logs



Failed to connect with Solana RPC node on localhost, its raise connection timeout error
